# Linq group by count and order by last update of the group

Tags: c#, linq

I need to display the groupby count according to the descending order of count number followed by order of the last update row (CreatedDateTime desc). How can this be done using LINQ?

```
TableA.GroupBy(c => c.UserID).Select(
                    g => new { UserID = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
                ).OrderByDescending(c => c.Count)
```

Here's an example of the intended ordering.

```
Table A
TableAID  UserID  TableBID CreatedDateTime
1         1       1        ..
2         1       1        ..
3         2       2        ..
4         2       2        ..
......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (I hope) :-)

```
TableA.GroupBy(c => c.UserID)
       .Select(g => new { UserID = g.Key, Count = g.Count(), g.Max(h => h.CreatedDateTime) })
       .OrderByDescending(c => c.Count)
       .ThenByDescending(c => c.CreatedDateTime)
```

Note that I selected the `Max(CreatedDateTime)`. I could have used the `Min(CreatedDateTime)`, but the result would have been different.

Comment: fabulous, this is what i needed. will upvote the answer later